# How to add multi-image streams into a AVI file

Tags: c++, c, video, video-streaming, avi

I'm making a AVI file from the image-frames by using C/C++ project as the following input:

1. stream1:

   - frame per second: 12 fps
   - number of frames: 500
2. stream2:

   - frame per second: 10 fps
   - number of frames: 600
3. stream3:

   - frame per second: 15 fps
   - number of frames: 700

Using the [avi_utils](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/avi_utils.html) library, I've tried with the `AddAviFrame()` function to add these frames into the AVI file. By this way, I can only create a frame-stream with the frame rate corresponding. 
**Is it possible to add more than one stream with different frame rates into an AVI file? If it is then how can I do it**. 
I also tried to call the release function `AVIStreamRelease()` then open another stream `AVIFileCreateStream()` but it didn't work. Please show me how can I resolve this case.

```
HAVI CreateAvi(const char *AVIFileName, int frameperiod, const WAVEFORMATEX *wfx)
{ 
  IAVIFile *pfile;
  AVIFileInit();
  HRESULT hr = AVIFileOpen(&pfile, AVIFileName, OF_WRITE|OF_CREATE, NULL);
  if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {AVIFileExit(); return NULL;}
  TAviUtil *au = new TAviUtil;
  au->pfile = pfile;
  if (wfx==NULL) ZeroMemory(&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)); else  CopyMemory(&au->wfx,wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
  au->period = frameperiod;
  au->as=0; au->ps=0; au->psCompressed=0;
  au->nframe=0; au->nsamp=0;
  au->iserr=false;
  return (HAVI)au;
}
HRESULT AddAviFrame(HAVI avi, HBITMAP hbm)
{ 
  if (au->ps==0) // create the stream, if it wasn't there before
  { AVISTREAMINFO strhdr; ZeroMemory(&strhdr,sizeof(strhdr));
    strhdr.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;// stream type
    strhdr.fccHandler = 0; 
    strhdr.dwScale = au->period;
    strhdr.dwRate = 1000;
    strhdr.dwSuggestedBufferSize  = dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage;
    SetRect(&strhdr.rcFrame, 0, 0, dibs.dsBmih.biWidth, dibs.dsBmih.biHeight);
    HRESULT hr=AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->ps, &strhdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  }
  //Now we can add the frame
  HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->psCompressed, au->nframe, 1, dibs.dsBm.bmBits, dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, NULL, NULL);
  if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
  au->nframe++; return S_OK;
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: The avi_utils library is a slightly higher level abstraction from the [MS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd756805(v=vs.85).aspx). You should try with that API instead. For instance the function [AVIFileCreateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd756793(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to allow that possibility.

Comment: @didierc: Thanks for very fast reply and your suggestion. Let me try with the MS API it looks very clear and maybe it will be able to help me solve my problem.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot help further as I don't have the knowledge of this particular API.